# How is my Google App Script Still Running Code I Took Out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

How do I still have a strand of code that is still performing itself when I took it completely out from my Google script? I deleted the code and saved the changes, and it's still running after a few commands (It's a onEdit function). Do I need to clear something out? If so, what and where?

Comment: If you are running your script as an add-on, you will need to [deploy a new version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments). Otherwise if it is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) it's possible that either the function began executing before your changes were saved, or you just need to refresh the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi @Altigraph! Thank you for your reply. So it is a simple trigger and I did have the action that it is performing happen before I made changes. But I deleted that action that it is performing from my Google Script, saved it inside the IDE, perform a few more actions on my spreadsheet and it is still running the same code.  I also tried to refresh the page, but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by "still running" - if your script is container-bound and using no versioned deployments there should not be any problem. If you'd updated the question with an [*execution transcript*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) and a *sample of your code*, we might be able to tell, what's wrong

Comment: Hello everyone. My apologies for the late reply. I did find my mistake. It turned out that it was a "}" error. I'm not sure entirely how that became the case, but I eventually got everything to run the way I wanted. Thank you all again for your input!